# What are required environment variables for GPG?

Tags: linux, gpg, key

I'm trying to setup the docker credentials, and it requires to initialize the `gpg` first.

Here are my steps:

```
root@remote_machine:~# gpg --gen-key                                                                   
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Note: Use "gpg --full-generate-key" for a full featured key generation dialog.

GnuPG needs to construct a user ID to identify your key.

Real name: NeededUser
Email address: mymail@mail.com
You selected this USER-ID:
    "NeededUser <mymail@mail.com>"

Change (N)ame, (E)mail, or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Required environment variable not set
Key generation failed: Required environment variable not set
root@remote_machine:~#
```

I have tried to set up the GPG_TTY variable, and it is set to `/dev/pts/0`. What variables are necessary for GPG?

Answer (score 1):

I was using kitty as the terminal emulator.
Switching to the konsole resolved it to me

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue using kitty as the terminal emulator, over ssh. Using xterm solved my problem. The thing is that at the end of the configuration, gpg ask for a passphrase in a kind of window that kitty may not support over ssh.

[xterm gpg window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypVTA.png)